# Renaming the initials in word comments

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office, microsoft-word-2007

Is there a way to go through and change the initials of comments made in a word document?

Answer (score 3):

This VBA macro will change all existing [initials of comments](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff195134%28v=office.14%29.aspx).

```
Sub ChangeInitialsAndAuthor()
    For Each MyComment In ActiveDocument.Comments
        If MyComment.Initial = "old" Then MyComment.Initial = "new"
    Next
End Sub
```

#### How to use the macro

- Open your Word file and press <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd> to open the VBA editor
- Insert a new module and copy & paste the code above
- Change `old` to your old initials and `new` to your new initials
- Run the macro with <kbd>F5</kbd> from the editor or <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F8</kbd> from word

Answer (score 1):

You can do it this way but it will change the name/initials used in ALL Microsoft Office products.

*Cut'n'pasted from the Office 2007 Help file.*

> On the Review tab, in the Tracking group, click the arrow next to Track Changes, and then click Change User Name

Comment: But does this change the initials in comments already posted, or just new comments?

Comment: Sorry for the delay, 2007 is only one my home PC. - I've just tried it and it keeps the original initials in the previous comments even after saving/reopening. Only new comments get the new initials.

Comment: So I guess its not possible, darn it.